# Touch event in UIScrollView send to back tableview

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview, touch

I have a problem for detect touch.

I put a view with TableView. Whem I select a row, add new view with ScrollView. The ScrollView put on TableView, but is a ScrollView with clearColor background and can see the back TableView. I need touch on ScrollView and send the touch for detect the row selected for user.

I can detect the touch in ScrollView whit touchBegan, and I send the touch to the back tableView view, but the didSelectRow don't detect the touch, only detect the touch if I put in the tableView view other touchBegan, but I need send the touch for select the row selected.

Thank you very much!!

```
         First View
-----------------------------
-         -                 - 
-         -                 - 
-    T    -                 - 
-    A    -                 - 
-    B    -                 - 
-    L    -                 - 
-    E    -                 - 
-    V    -                 - 
-    I    -                 - 
-    E    -                 - 
-    W    -                 - 
-         -                 - 
-         -                 - 
-----------------------------


        Second View  --> ##### is the ScrollView area on tableView FirstView
-----------------------------
-   -######                 - 
-   -######                 - 
-   -######                 - 
-   -######                 - 
-   -######                 - 
-   -######   SCROLL        - 
-   -######    VIEW         - 
-   -######                 - 
-   -######                 - 
-   -######                 - 
-   -######                 - 
-   -######                 - 
-   -######                 - 
-----------------------------
```

######  I need touch on this position and select the row in back tableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you determine that the touch needs to be passed on in your scroll view's touchesBegan method, call

```
[self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
```

to pass the event down the chain instead of attempting to call the touchesBegan method of the parent view directly.

Comment: Thanks John! but don't work for me :(, I use these line and I put self.nextResponder or super or [self superview] but don't work, only can capture the event if I put a method touchesBegan in the first view, but the tableview cell don't selected because de didSelectionRow don't is call.

Comment: This only works if the top view is a subview of the back view, not if both are in the same hierarchy.